# GitHub Actions deploy a react + express app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to set up a deployment using GitHub actions. Build the React app and use express to serve it.

```yaml
name: EB Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_DEFAULT_REGION }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Python 3.9
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.9
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
          pip install awsebcli
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16'
      - name: Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk
        run: |
          cd client
          npm i
          npm run build
          mv dist ..
          cd ..
          eb deploy
```

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './dist')))
```

Everything works fine except `eb` doesn't deploy `dist` folder.

Even when I run `eb labs download` to download the deployed version I don't see `dist` folder in the zip file.

I ended up zipping the whole dir and `eb deploy --staged` it, for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `eb` was ignoring the `dist` folder because it wasn't being tracked by git. I added these commands:

```
          git config --global user.email "GH-DEPLOY@aws.null"
          git config --global user.name "GH-DEPLOY"
          git add dist
          git commit -m 'add react app'
          eb deploy --staged
```